# Getting a zero p-value with Wilcoxon test in Matlab

Tags: hypothesis-testing, matlab, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I'm creating a classification model for detection of stress. I'm trying to select the best features from 56 total.

I have a matrix of `1937x56` with the non stress data, and a matrix of `1763x56` for stress data.

`f_n -> non-stress matrix` and `f_s -> the stress one`

I'm using `Matlab` and here's my code.

```
rank = zeros(1,size(f_n,2));

for l = 1:size(f_n,2)
    rank(1,l) = ranksum(f_n(:,l), f_s(:,l));
end
```

the think is I'm getting some `p-values` equal to zero.

Here's the output of `rank`

```
3.23970807719953e-59    1.19012268294050e-32    1.24342293425171e-123   2.98338574026435e-227   1.94090447559927e-227   7.54664151060207e-250   8.99703327997911e-292   1.38826281436916e-298   4.78404773111577e-308   2.15213684390080e-37    0.000196579371678330    4.25370029962320e-27    4.90973329410252e-166   9.84016939125288e-200   4.84716291687399e-277   3.52745590178140e-287   2.81025758599302e-297   7.01405396494596e-289   3.30447666181206e-165   1.73163324556308e-32    1.06353645618514e-116   6.74904729244135e-130   3.77342641391818e-173   4.64192483365192e-239   1.60123198146693e-250   1.16096192265296e-259   1.31621596229152e-271   0.00115260954904737 5.11414519751266e-253   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5.53879714415676e-137   5.61283198666988e-67    2.53913294535256e-177   0   0   0   0   0   0   1.70864676934011e-91    4.50477630440800e-73    1.34942550217303e-165   4.91843135947255e-180   8.45438406534899e-209   1.02062206403179e-213   1.26764781876251e-214   6.91325407956207e-247   2.35709504234097e-276   0   1.11140566121933e-36
```

I don't think it is supposed to be really zero.

Any help?

Comment: Your sample sizes are large. Why do you think the values are wrong?

Comment: To be more specific, "exact" zeros are probably just too small to represent.

Comment: @Glen_b yes, it's probably that but I want to represent them not as zero.

Comment: What possible point is there in representing a p-value smaller than even `1.e-10` as anything but `0`? Note that the assumptions are never *perfectly* satisfied, so a value far out into the tail, like `1.19e-32` generally won't even have a *single digit* of accuracy as an approximation to the true p-value, and when we get down to `2.98e-227`, you're not even talking about rough, handwavy approximation any more. It's a quantity without any meaning, relying heavily on not-quite-true assumptions, but which could change markedly with even mild changes to those assumptions. To what purpose?

Comment: ... and that's without even considering the issues with floating point arithmetic. When you pile a p-value that cannot be accurate - even if you could do the calculation you're attempting perfectly - with the unavoidable loss of accuracy with floating point arithmetic (getting much worse as you get down to very small quantities), and what are you really doing? Pushing around noise to try to estimate a quantity that isn't exactly the thing you actually want it to be. Might as well take the lucky numbers from the horoscope page and stick ".e-500" on the end.

Comment: @Glen_b So how can I represent and interpret this values?

Comment: Once a p-value is extremely small, the interpretation is "the p-value is extremely small". When it is too small to represent, yielding a value that is represented as zero, you could always note that the value is 'too small to represent'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want help with, since the call to [ranksum](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ranksum.html) looks correct. You should be aware that floating point numbers, due to how they're represented, are not exact, so your zeros may not be "true" zeros, but actually just very small numbers (on the order of eps(0)).

Using a significance test seems a little odd for feature selection. It might be a decent first step, but presumably you'd want to eliminate highly correlated factors too.

*** Edit: More on floating point***

The short answer is that you can't really. You can coax matlab into displaying a few more decimal places by typing `format longg` (with 2 g's), but beyond that....

Matlab, like nearly everything else, uses IEEE-754 Floating Point, which has a finite amount of precision. The `eps` function tells the next largest magnitude number--you can think of it as the "step size", if that helps, or that for any number $\epsilon<eps(x)$,  $x+\epsilon==x$. This arises from how computers represent floating point numbers (if you are curious, I recommend  ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)). There *are* libraries that can represent decimal values to an arbitrary precision, but they're fairly specialized and I can't think of any that also include statistical tests.

The more important question is whether you need to care. If you need to report the aparently-zero $p$-values, you could write $p<5 \times10^{-324}$ (i.e., `eps(0)`), and you could use that "upper bound" if you were doing something with the $p$-values, like multiple comparisons correction.

Most importantly, I'd encourage you not to over-interpret the absolute values. While this is the definition of a $p$-value, I'm not sure I would believe that you'll only see a difference this extreme much fewer than one in a googol times if there's no difference between your groups.

Comment: how can I increase the acuuracy so I can see than them not as exact zeros?

Comment: the `eps(rank)` gives me numbers as `4.9 e^-324` now instead of zeros.